# Files are corrupted after recovery with easeus

Tags: macos

Something really really bad happened to me. I was formatting my SD Card with the Terminal when suddenly something happened and it formatted my ext. Hard drive.

After that, I found the software "easeus data recovery" but every file I recover is corrupted, but the file size is the same as the original one.

**Here some data from me:**

- System (OS): macOS High Sierra V. 10.13.4
- Hard drive before: Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
- Hard drive after: Fat
- Terminal command: `sudo diskutil eraseDisk FAT32 MYSD MBRFormat /dev/disk2`

**What I already tried:**

- Saving on an other Hard drive (Journaled and ExFat)

Does someone have a solution for that?

Comment: FAT[x] is a Windows format, no?

Comment: Yes it is, but the software (easeus) can read it.. and export the files to mac

Comment: I highly suggest not using that pos easeus. It has made small nightmares into bigger ones. Use either data rescue or disk drill.

Comment: You may want to reach out to the makers of easeus.